# why do I still need dimension if I have compression

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Recently I have some doubt, looking for answer.

Normally, when design a data warehouse, either we use star model or snowflake model or hybrid, and normally we normalize the master data into dimension tables(certainly sometimes for performance consideration, de-normalize). My question is, normalization into dimension table, or create all kinds of different dimension tables, what is the benefit?

**If for saving space, then the SQL Server different level of compression already saves the space.** 
For instance, in a fact table, there is a varchar(max) column, which only has 1% of unique value, then normalize it to dimension table, and put key in fact table, it will help saving space; however, because of SQL row level compression, it works theoretically the same way, instead normalized by your own design, SQL Server will find the string pattern and save somewhere, within the row is only the pointer, so the space usage is theoretically like the key.

**If for improving query performance,** then with dimension table, no matter what index you have on dimension, you need to at least first non-cluster index scan/index seek your dimension table to get the key, then using key to get cluster index/or RID, then get the full data. That is 2 times I/O. If without dimension, you still have the index on fact table, the corresponding column, because of compression, you index table will be similar size as you create index on dimension table. So, when you query, probably it is also one time non-cluster index scan/cluster index seek/then full data, so the I/O probably can be even smaller, and plus without join, the query performance probably can be even faster.

**So, why do I need dimension if I already have compression?**

Comment: A well designed star schema is compressed by the virtue of using the smallest datatypes possible. I don't see a real question here. Dimensions are there for the end user's ease of slicing/dicing.

Comment: Could you kindly share more light regarding to "A well designed star schema is compressed by the virtue of using the smallest datatypes possible". And also Dimensions are there for the end user's ease of slicing/dicing, will end user really use dimension table or most case they are just using view?

Comment: How is it harder to analyze a fully denormalized table vs a star schema?

Answer (score 2):

Dimensional models are not all about the physical design of the database. If you find that performance is better when you create a star schema in the "view layer" and underneath are 3NF tables, great!

The star schema is to allow report writers and end users to be able to access data from many sources that can be then aggregated and analyzed in many different ways. If I have to write a report that shows "average number of late invoices for customers with > $10000 in sales of products that are in category x", a normalized model will require that I go to each sub-table of the sales system, possibly resulting in a query with 10 - 50 joins!

Imagine that I'm a report writer, and when I want to do something different I have to remember all those joins... or worse, I'm a business user writing basic SQL, I dont' have the first clue how to do so many joins.

So instead, the hard work of identifying the business relationships in the data is done up front, and fact tables are built that connect my invoice data together with the descriptive data related to it. Now, I just query the customer total sales by product fact, then take the resulting set of customers, and join to the invoice fact (or even a prebuilt aggregation) to get the average # of late invoices. maybe 2-4 table joins, and much easier on the report writer.

Comment: How does a star schema help this over a completely denormalized table?

Comment: Some data is at different granularity than others. If I have invoice data and manufacturing data that is related through some common dimensions, I want to be able to do distinct reporting on the separate parts as well as the whole. Additionally, many dimensions have hundreds of columns, many of which may be null or sparse - the denormalized table itself then becomes more complicated than a star, since I have to identify the grain of the data I need and do "distinct" operations and grouping operations.

Comment: Fact tables are fully normalized - they're full of keys relating to tables that are fully denormalized. From a business perspective, having my customer information in one table and product information in another allows me to query those dimensions directly, as well as the fact. If I fully denormalized everything, many questions couldn't be answered - "how many products do I have?" - only those products with a transaction would even appear on the "fully denormalized table".

Comment: Note that I have evolved in my thinking and would not necessarily recommend a Kimball-style approach to anything. However, as you will hear that from the majority of data warehouse people, I'll leave the answer as is. In this case however, there may be some validity to creating a star-style view layer for ease of use by business users.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you're correlating compression and dimensions. The whole point of a warehouse is to forget about compression and normalization and model something that would require least number of table joins so as to fetch the data as fast as possible.

Just assume you have a 3D model of your future house kept on a table. You would want to see the model from all angles so that you know more about the house. Similarly, we have dimensions so that we can view the data from all angles possibles. This is what Mitch meant when he said 'slicing and dicing'.

Vijay.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider changes to dimensional values.

If one of your customers gets married and you need to search your data by current marital status, do you want to:

1. Update a single dimension record for that customer, or ...
2. Update every historical record in the fact table for that customer?

One of the key principles of normalisation is that you save each item of information only in a single location, and that doesn't change with data warehouses.